# Store variables on a new dimension in a nested for loop python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, append, concatenation

I am new to Python- trying to move from Matlab

I am reading multiple .nc files using for loop and am trying to save them along a new record dimension.A section of the code below. `j` and `j1` has a size of 4x30x30 and  I am trying to store data of `j` in variable `appn` for the 3 `e` along the 0th dim, such that `appn` is a variable with size 3x4x30x30.
It is simple in Matlab, but could not figure out a way in Python

```
import os, sys
import netCDF4
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cdo import *
import xarray as xr
cdo=Cdo()

indices = ["T"]
models = ["MJ", "MK", "ML"]
seasons =["JJA", "DJF"]
period =["base", "proj"]
exp = ["ssp1", "ssp2", "ssp3"]
odir = "/outs_pytry/season/"
top ="/outs_pytry/monmean_1/"
os.makedirs(odir, exist_ok=True)
#appn=[]
appnx=[]
#pr_arr = np.zeros([models,nlat,nlon], dtype='f4')
#pr_arr = np.zeros([], dtype='f4')
j=[]    
for m in models:
        folder = "%s"%(top)
        if m in ["ML"]:
            run = "r1i1p1f2"
        else:
            run = "r1i1p1f1"
        for i in indices:
                for e in exp:
                
                  origfi1 = '%s%s_%s_%s_%s_base.nc'%(folder,i, m, e, run)
                  origfi2 = '%s%s_%s_%s_%s_proj.nc'%(folder,i, m, e, run)
                                       
                    
                  k=cdo.timselmean(3,11,9, input="%s"%origfi1, output="%s%s_%s_%s_%s_DJF_proj.nc"%(odir,i,m,e,run), returnCdf=True)
                  k1=cdo.timselmean(3,5,9, input="%s"%origfi1, output="%s%s_%s_%s_%s_JJA_proj.nc"%(odir,i,m,e,run), returnCdf=True)
                           
                  j=k.variables["T"][:]
                  
                  j1=k1.variables["T"][:]
                  
    
                  lat=k.variables["lat"]
                  lon=k.variables["lon"]
    
                  #appn=np.zeros([3,4,lon,lat], dtype='f4')
                  datain = np.array(j)

                  #Confused with how to store data in appn , so that it has a fourth dimension of size 'e'?
                  appn(e,:,:,:) =datain
                  appn.append(datain)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. This code includes redundant imports and commented out code, so there is far too much to wade through.

Answer (score 0):

in python you can append to a list dictionaries or lists. if you want to append to appn a dictionary with all if detains variables, plus "e" you can do it like this: {"e":e,**datain}.

if you only want to append an array of the values to appn use: [e,*datain.values()] to create a list and then append it. I put an example below

```
import os, sys
import netCDF4
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cdo import *
import xarray as xr
cdo=Cdo()

indices = ["T"]
models = ["MJ", "MK", "ML"]
seasons =["JJA", "DJF"]
period =["base", "proj"]
exp = ["ssp1", "ssp2", "ssp3"]
odir = "/outs_pytry/season/"
top ="/outs_pytry/monmean_1/"
os.makedirs(odir, exist_ok=True)
#appn=[]
appnx=[]
#pr_arr = np.zeros([models,nlat,nlon], dtype='f4')
#pr_arr = np.zeros([], dtype='f4')
j=[]
j1=[]
appn=[]
for m in models:
    
    folder = "%s"%(top)
    if m in ["ML"]:
        run = "r1i1p1f2"
    else:
        run = "r1i1p1f1"
    for i in indices:
        for e in exp:
          origfi1 = '%s%s_%s_%s_%s_base.nc'%(folder,i, m, e, run)
          origfi2 = '%s%s_%s_%s_%s_proj.nc'%(folder,i, m, e, run)


          k=cdo.timselmean(3,11,9, input="%s"%origfi1, output="%s%s_%s_%s_%s_DJF_proj.nc"%(odir,i,m,e,run), returnCdf=True)
          k1=cdo.timselmean(3,5,9, input="%s"%origfi1, output="%s%s_%s_%s_%s_JJA_proj.nc"%(odir,i,m,e,run), returnCdf=True)

          j=k.variables["T"][:]
          j1=k1.variables["T"][:]

          lat=k.variables["lat"]
          lon=k.variables["lon"]

          #appn=np.zeros([3,4,lon,lat], dtype='f4')
          datain = np.array(j)
          appn.append({"e":e,**datain}) # appn.append([e,*datain.values()])
```

Comment: This does not work unfortunately,  throws the error -  'numpy.ndarray' object is not a mapping

Comment: my bad I thought datain was a dictionary. but is actually a list.

appn.append([e,*j]) 

or if you want it as np.array: 

datain = np.array([e,*j])
appn.append(datain)